# CEF in windows phone app

Tags: windows-phone-8, chromium-embedded

Can I use Chrome embedded framework in my windows phone project, is it support touche event, and other mobile-need features? If it's impossible is there other solve for this mobile os?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot embed the Chrome web browser inside of a Windows Phone project.

The `WebBrowser` ([reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)) is the best control for embedding a web browser in your phone project.